# how to prevent user's cart item from deleting if clicked on delete

Tags: php

if user have save any item in cart and when he logout the items are still visible in cart page even though user have logout  and when we try to delete the item it deletes the item that is store in users cart as well.

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
$bkid=$_GET['delete_id'];
$sql1="DELETE FROM `add_cart` WHERE `book_id`='$bkid'";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
header('location:cart.php');
?>
```

now i want a code where i can individually delete the cart item like if not login then prevent the user cart item from deleting

Comment: You must check if the user is logged in or not.. like you do in other places..

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the user is logged in or not.. like you do in other places.. Something like:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();

if (is_logged()) {
    $bkid=$_GET['delete_id'];
    $sql1="DELETE FROM `add_cart` WHERE `book_id`='$bkid'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
}

header('location:cart.php');
```

Also, **notice** that you must prevent **SQL injection** as you don't escape the `delete_id` parameter.